# Can you hold right-click to place blocks in a line in Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Bedrock Edition, if you hold down the right mouse button when placing blocks, it places them in a line no matter how you move your mouse. It stays to one line and keeps placing in a row or column even as you run away or fly away fast.

Java Edition doesn't lock the block placement like this, so my blocks get placed too randomly and all over the place whenever I build… :/

Can you do the same thing somehow in Java Edition? Is there a setting or any other solution?

Comment: A video would be helpful, because not many people actively play both. But your description sounds to me like something the "Tweakeroo" mod lets you do.

Comment: A video would be helpful, but I think the question is very clear: the two editions treat placing blocks differently, so "how can the placing-blocks-in-one-line behaviour from BE be acquired in JE"?

Comment: @Joachim The request for a video was before two substantial edits that added a lot of clarity to the question (or so I'd like to believe, as one of the editors ;) )

Comment: @Schism Ah, that makes more sense then, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting, there are mods for example [this](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/accurate-block-placement) for fabric.